# Nested model and multi search criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Thanks in advance for any kind of help you will provide me :)

To explain my problem, lets consider this :

- I have a Car model
- Each car has many oil type
- Oil Model contains oil informations (Chemistry) and a type

I want to build a search algorithm based on chemistry criterias. For example, a user can request an oil with lower than 30% of a molecule and more than 5% of another...

I have tones of informations in this Oil table and I'd like to allow the user to filter on every criteria he wants. It could be a single request or a far more complex one with thousands of criterias.

Does anyone have an idea about how can I implement that? I'm a beginner with ruby and its web framework (ruby on rails).

Thanks :)

Comment: Your question is too broad for StackOverflow. There are many ways you could solve this, either with fully custom code or utilising [a popular gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). In order to be a good SO question, you need to show *what you have tried so far* (and what's missing/wrong with your current attempt).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your link. Its seems to be a good starting point for me :)